# 'Group' is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as an alias, unless it is escaped

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, reserved-words

I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 with repository pattern (Database is already existing).
My problem is the existence of a table called GROUP (which is reserved). This is a production database which i cannot change.

So, using all this techniques above i'm getting the following error:

'Group' is a reserved keyword and cannot be used as an alias, unless it is escaped.

Is it possible to tell Entity Framework to use the following as the table name:
[GROUP]

**EDIT**
The class with the db context looks like the following (stripped down)

```
 public class AMTDatabase : DbContext
    {

      private IDbSet<GROUP> _Groups;
      public IDbSet<GROUP> Group
      {
        get { return _Groups ?? (_Groups = DbSet<GROUP>()); }
      }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {        
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
      modelBuilder.Entity<GROUP>().ToTable("GROUP");      
    }
    //etc
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Who is giving you this error? Is it in Visual Studio or its your database? Can you post the code of your class that has the problem?

Comment: @AlexandreJobin: i'm getting the error in VS. See also the EDIT.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems very weird, but notice the property name above: the name is Group and it should read Groups! This is the reason i'm getting this error. The corrected code is the following:

```
private IDbSet<GROUP> _Groups;
        public IDbSet<GROUP> Groups
        {
            get { return _Groups ?? (_Groups = DbSet<GROUP>()); }
        }
```

Works like a charm now!

Comment: Just found the same and the result seems very weird to me. Even using `context.Set<Group>().ToList()` works, but `context.Group.ToList()` doesn't. Strange...

Comment: So what does this mean ... i'm confused! Can't we choose whatever name we would like for the DBSet??

Comment: So it looks like. I've just tested to give `DbSet<Group>` names like `Select`, `Join` and `Where`. They all throw the same exception. EF seems to check against a list of SQL keywords. The entity name `Group` itself is not the problem.

Comment: You 're right! Having a look at the mapping instruction tells us that the entity name can be ... whatever! BUT the DBSet cannot. Well, learned something new today!! Thank very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another naming for you class and tell him to use the Group table in your database like so:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{        
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyGroup>().ToTable("GROUP");      
}
```

Or with the attributes directly on your entity class:

```
[Table("Group")]
public class MyGroup
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("GroupId")]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
}
```